# python icmp raw socket implementation

Tags: python, icmp, raw-sockets

i am relatively new to python, so please be considerate...

i'm implementing a server and a client via raw_sockets.
i have the necessary privileges.

now, the **server** i defined so:

```
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
address = (host, 22224)
sockSer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
sockSer.bind(address)
sockSer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
packet, addr = sockSer .recvfrom(4096)   # wait for packet from client
```

**Q1)** why can't i simply type: hosts = 'localhost'.
if i do so, it doesn't allow me to write the line: sockSer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON). and then the server doesn't receive my client's messages.
only when doing gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) i get 192.168.1.101 
and then it works.

in a different class:
the **client** socket:

```
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
address = (host, 22224)
sockCli = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
```

**Q2)** do i also need to type: sockCli.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
or maybe sockCli.connect(address)? seems that it works without the connect command. 
for the client socket?

now, the problems arise when i do the following:
1) send a packet from client to server:

```
header=...
payload='a'
sockCli.sendto(header + payload, address)
```

2) receive packet in server and send something back to client:

```
while(true):
    data, addr = sockSer.recvfrom(4096)
    header2=...
    payload2='b'
    sockSer.sendto(header2 + payload2, addr)
```

now, my important question is:
**Q3)** the server sent only 1 packet to client, with payload 'b'.
what happens is, my client actually receives 2 packets in the while loop:
first packet is what **the client itself sent to server**, and the other packet is what the client got from the server.
hence my output is 'ab' instead of simply 'b'
why is this happening???

NOTE: i didn't type the entire code, but i think my syntax,parsing,header composition etc.. are correct.
is there an obvious problem in my code?
if necessary i'll upload the entire code.

thanks

Comment: Raw sockets ought to work just fine on the loopback interface unless your system is configured to not allow them.

Comment: Internet Control Message Protocol sockets are not used to send data to/from hosts, it's just for sending short control messages to hosts. That's why there is no need for it to be connected.

Comment: By the way, what is the reason you want to use ICMP (which really isn't supposed to be used for data transfer) instead of, say, normal UDP?

Comment: it's an exercise i gotta do. so i DO want to send data via icmp.
I want to embed the data, say 2 bytes, in the id field.
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I got this too.
my solution is add a judge in the receive code,such as  if I send Ping package so I only want ECHO　Reply( type 0 code 0), I write

```
if type != 0:
     continue
```

and you also can write as
    if addr == my_ip:
         continue

It seems not has any smooth solution

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I was able to bind to localhost and call IOCTL with both parameters just fine. Assuming your client is also running on the same system, ensure the client is sending to "localhost", otherwise your server will never receive the packets. If your client is on another system, obviously your server will never receive the packets.

Q2: You do not need IOCTL for sending the packet. Just send it via sendto().

Q3: The reason you're seeing two replies is, the kernel is also processing the echo request, in addition to your own user-space code.

Although you can use ICMP for arbitrary message passing, as someone else pointed out this isn't its intended design. You may find that your data portion is truncated out in message replies. For example, when sending echo requests, your reply likely will contain everything you sent; however, a reply that is type 3 code 3 may not include your data, but only the first 8 bytes of the ICMP header.